# NPN Relay Driver Problem

Tags: circuit-design, relay, gpio, npn

I've designed what I thought would be a simple relay driver circuit to drive a relay with a raspberry pi GPIO pin (which is pulled down with a 50K resistor internally).  In the circuit diagram, pin 6 on the relay is connected to +5v, but that didn't make it into the image. The relay is used to isolate the circuit and pi from a second device.  The relay pulls a pin to ground on the second device (GNDS, not circuit GND).

I originally breadboarded this circuit and had no issues whatsoever, it worked perfectly for weeks.  Then I built the circuit on a protoboard and immediately ran into problems with the relay actuating randomly.  Sometimes once a minute, sometimes several times per second.  I tried adding a small filter capacitor to the base of the transistor, I've double and triple checked my solder connections, replaced components(same model, but different part).  No luck.  I designed a PCB for the circuit and built it, and I had the same issues as the protoboard.  I've breadboarded it again and it works just fine!

Can anyone see what I've done wrong or suggest something I should try?

Thanks.

The full schematic can be found here:https://ve7mhw.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/9/9/129977040/pcb.pdf

[image: NPN Relay Driver]

[image: Breadboard]

[image: Protoboard]

[image: PCB]

Comment: What happens to LED D3 when the relay activates randomly? I assume it goes on. If you remove the relay, does D3 activate randomly by itself? If you put an o'scope probe on pin 26/37 does it activate randomly?

Comment: Yes, D3 does come on each time the relay activates, so I assume that my issue is with the transistor.  Unfortunately, I don't have an oscilloscope, I haven't tried pulling out the relay, I will try that and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a logic probe? If not, could you solder a small red LED to a 2.2K resistor, and use that to check to see if pin 26/37 actives randomly?

Comment: I will test 26/37 with an LED.

Comment: That ribbon to bread-board interface PCB is nice - would you mind sharing where you sourced it?

Comment: Is the problem that the relay (a) turns ON randomly when it should be OFF, or (b) turns OFF randomly when it should be ON?  If (a) then I suggest putting a 10K resistor across BE of Q2.  If (b) then most likely there is a bad connection somewhere in the coil current path (from the +5V supply through the coil and back to the negative of the +5V supply), (please refer to my longer answer).

Comment: While I am waiting for your results, the next thing I would check is whether you have the BJT wired backward. (I've done it, and so has everyone). You could be experiencing random reverse breakdown current. Test to see that pin 3 is connected to ground using a multimeter with the power to your circuit off.

Comment: I am confused somewhat.  Does the schematic reflect the actual circuit in all cases?  For example, I cannot see D4 in either the "shield" or the PCB marked "VE7MHW", but it seems to be visible on the prototyping board (sitting above the relay).

On the "shield" (photo #3/4) what is the black two-leaded component sitting between the two resistors?

Comment: As mentioned by Fabio, the diodes on the relay coil(s) seem to misplaced, or at the very least far from the coil pins.  The inductive spike coming from a switched relay coil should be shunted as close as possible to the coil pins.  If the spike reaches other components before it reaches the diode that could create a problem. As for other connections on the finished board: Did you run a DRC after completing the final routing stage? Were there any unknown or unconfirmed errors or warnings?

Comment: @Nedd, good eye, the diodes on the protoboard are soldered underneath, directly to the relay pins.  There was nothing out of the ordinary on the PCB design, but I'm very new to this so there very well could have been and I just didn't know what I was looking at.

Comment: @FabioBarone, I'm not exactly sure where I got the ribbon to breadboard interface, however, Adafruit sells one just like it here: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2028  or if you're in Canada as well, then BC Robotics is a reseller here: https://bc-robotics.com/shop/adafruit-pi-t-cobbler-plus-breakout/

Comment: @FabioBarone The schematic is a reflection of all versions, I didn't post the full schematic as to not add complexity to the post, but there are 2 relays and accompanying components.  I will edit the original post with a copy of the full schematics and respond further to your longer post,  Thank you.

Comment: The schematic looks fine. Outside of a damaged RPi or wiring problem, the only thing I can imagine that could cause this is some unintended connection between the board and something on the RPi underneath it. Put some card between them and see what happens.

Comment: Try putting a resistor across the base-emitter junction of Q2. 390 to 1k ohm.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you've given me lots of great suggestions and I'll let you know how it pans out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, lets examine the relay coil.  Part no: HK4100F-DC5V-SHG.  Datasheet (link 1 below) says this has a resistance of 125ohm (the "H" in "SHG" indicates coil power of 0.2W).  At 5V this draws 40mA, and the parallel LED indicator draws about 2mA, which we can ignore.

The BC337 transistor datasheet (link 2 below) specifies all data regarding saturation mode with a collector current to base current ratio of 10, so that means in this case applying base current of 4mA to be able to apply the datasheet specs.  However, having used this transistor many times, Ic=40mA represents a relatively low current, and a ratio of 20 for base current will be more than enough to ensure it is fully saturated, so let's go for 2mA of base drive.

That means the base current limiting resistor can be selected based on:
(Vo - 0.7V) / 2mA,
where Vo is the output voltage of the Raspberry Pi GPIO pin.  Assuming that is 3.3V, then you could probably increase R2 from 390r to, say, 1k without too much concern, which reduces the current the GPIO pin has to supply, which is a good start.

The next issue to look at is the coil current path.  It flows from the +5V supply to the gnd via Q2.  Please ensure that this current path, including all the wires that go between the two PCAs (the Raspberry Pi, and the PCA with the relay) are low impedance, and have good connections.  Think like an electron, and follow the complete path all the way from the +5V power supply negative terminal, all the way to +5V supply positive terminal (or use conventional current flow from positive to negative if you prefer).  You need to ensure that this path has low impedance, and is not being affected by other currents from other devices that could cause the coil current to reduce unexpectedly.  Is there a bad solder join, or perhaps a connector pin that is being asked to carry more current than it should?

The next issue: Is the circuit immune to electromagnetic fields?  I would usually put a resistor across the base of Q2 to ensure it stays OFF when you turn it off.  Something like a 10k will be fine - this will rob about 0.07mA from the base drive when you turn it on, but since there is 2mA of drive available this won't be a problem.

You have D4 protecting Q2 from excessive voltage at coil turn-off, so all is good there.

I think if you follow the above you should be able to sort out your problem.

My gut feel is: a combination of (a) changing R2, (b) adding 10k across Q1 BE, and (c) ensuring a good current path for the coil current will fix your troubles.  I suspect one or more connections between the Rasberry Pi and your relay card may be not quite right.

Link 1:
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1493116/HUIKE/HK4100F-DC5V-SHG/1

Link 2:
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc337-d.pdf

Comment: Regaring your comments above, D4 is underneath the protoboard design soldered right to the relay pins, however, on the PCB, it is right below the GPIO pins.  I'm beginning to understand that putting it there was probably a mistake, as it should have been closer to the relay.  

Regarding the state of the relay, the problem is "a" the relay is coming on when it should be off.

The black component between the relays is just a jumper wire from the GPIO header to the prototyping area.

Comment: OK, if the problem is: "(a) the relay is coming on when it should be off", then I suggest making R2 bigger (~1K), and putting a 10K across Q2 BE.

Comment: @Matt Although I do agree with Fabio about adding the 10k resistor across the BE junction (cheap to do and helps avoid problems), pulling the relay in requires a fair bit of base current, which almost certainly cannot come from `static charges` or `charge storage` alone. Having problems with a solderless protoboard (with thick wires hanging all over the place and trace capacitances connecting everything) and a PCB (with exceptionally thin traces) while both times you built this on a breadboard it worked fine says that we likely cannot guess at the problem well. Can you scope circuit points?

Comment: I will try that, thank you for taking the time to post, there's a lot of good info here for me.

Comment: @Matt  If those two changes don't fix it, then the problem is more to do with the physical implementations.  So things like wiring, connections, stray capacitances, etc, all contribute.  

Question: is the unexpected turn-on of the relay very short in duration (<1 sec), or does it last several seconds?

Comment: @periblepsis  Yes, I agree that turning on a relay requires a large amount of base current and is unlikely to be due to static etc; however, if the base resistance is just 390r as per the schematic, then the **voltage** required to get Q2 to turn on **sufficiently** could be quite low, particularly if Q2 is operating in linear region and hence has high gain (>100).   Could be caused by some bump in GPIO output voltage due to some other load being switched.

Comment: @periblepsis unfortunately I don't have much in the way of test equipment beyond a basic multi-meter.  I concur, I had wondered if the thin traces on the PCB were causing problems, but since it happens on the protoboard as well, I had ruled out low current carrying capacity, stray capacitance or EM induced currents as likely culprits.

Comment: @Matt I also decided to set aside the thin traces for now, given the huge wires on the solderless breadboard. There's just too much difference between these scenarios that are failing you to imagine finding something in common between them that also isn't present on the breadboard case. I don't think there's much left over in the Venn diagram between these three cases. (Empty set.) So that means a scope. You can buy a really cheap, crappy, but relatively small and easy to use system for about $20. It's frequency response will be crappy, too. But good enough for this case. Can't you afford it?

Comment: @FabioBarone the unexpected turn-ons are generally short duration and very intermittent.  Sometimes it's once here and there, but most of the time it's many times per second.  The duration is also variable, it can switch on and off once and that's it for a time, or it can constantly oscillate until power is removed, and everything in between.

Comment: @periblepsis, I will have to look into getting a scope of some sort.  I just sort of dabble in this, so I haven't really invested much into equipment unless it crossed over into other interests.  It's probably time though!

Comment: @Matt The price you will have to pay in getting and using a scope is to learn to apply it and operate it, well. That's a cost you cannot avoid (learning experience.) But it is a worthy investment, if you will be doing any of this kind of stuff in the future. Given that you have already shown a serious engagement (and applied lots of time) learning other aspects, I think the relatively small investment (learning and money) for a scope will pay off well for you. I think you should bite that bullet. I'm worried about oscillations and about a few other things. But none good enough to write about.

Comment: @Matt Just FYI, from the relay datasheet I would estimate an inductance of about 600 mH to go with the 125 Ohms. (There will also be some small amount of parallel capacitance, but whatever that is likely helps you rather than hurting.) You may also want to include a series zener with the diode for faster turn-off (which also helps reduce wear on the contacts.) But that's about all. Everything else has already been discussed here.

Comment: @Matt  Re: "but most of the time it's many times per second. "  Hmmm, perhaps some mains hum is the culprit?  Or ripple on the power supply to the MCU?  You won't see any of that without a scope - perhaps measure the supply with your meter set to AC volts?  Anyhow, please try the two changes I suggested, let us know if that changes any behaviour.  Cheers.

Comment: @Matt The comments are getting quite excessive, this may be recommended for a chat session. You have several ideas to review and some changes to try. Getting a small scope may take a while. Last few things I would add: Go over all major point to point connections on the board with an ohm check. Look for possible cold solder joints, maybe resolder any that are suspect. Verify connections to all ground and power points, socket pins, I/O pins, etc. Maybe even try opening an I/O line and manually bring a line high and low. Let us know if you add more info or if some of the tips helped. Good luck.